# jQuery.getJSON - assign the data parameter to variable?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I cannot assign the data parameter of the jQuery.getJSON function to variable.

```
var storage;

$.getJSON('server.json', function(data) {
    storage = data;
});

console.log(storage);
```

EDIT : ok I understand, so let's say the 'storage' variable is equals the server.json file, but i can't use it because the lines of code below the $.getJSON executed before the server answered, so how can i check whenever the server is answered?

Comment: Think about this piece of code for a while. Why would `$.getJSON` have the additional complexity of using a callback if it ran synchronously...?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen but how can i still assign the JSON file to variable??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *"after that"*, you mean *"below in the code"*, I suppose.

If so, then it's not after the server answered.

Use this :

```
var storage;
$.getJSON('server.json', function(data) {
    storage = data;
    console.log(storage);
});
```

The callback you give to getJSON is called after the server has (asynchronously) answered. That's where you must handle the result. The lines of code just below `$.getJSON(...);` are executed **before** the server answered so they can't use the result.

Comment: @Israel: You can't do that. That's not how the event/callback driven model JS is based on works.

Comment: @IsraelG. You must understand what it means for a query to be asynchronous. A javascript application is event-driven (events being the response of a server or a user interaction). You must understand this point. You can't simply have a synchronous code.

Comment: @dystroy ok I understand, so let's say the 'storage' variable is equals the server.json file, but i can't use it because the lines of code below the $.getJSON executed before the server answered, so how can i check whenever the server is answered?

Comment: @IsraelG. You can call your method in the  ```$.getJSON()``` where the data is defined. Then your method will have access to the right data when it arrives. Thats asynchronous callback style